# How to send a POST request Through node.js to https website

Tags: node.js

request  NODEjs to https website and encodeurl

Answer (score 0):

Simple. use [request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) module

```
var request = require('request');

var formData = {
  // Pass a simple key-value pair 
  my_field: 'my_value'
};
request.post({url:'https://service.com/post', formData: formData}, function(err, httpResponse, body) {
  if (err) {
    return console.error('post failed:', err);
  }
  console.log('post successful!  Server responded with:', body);
});
```

if you want to use the basic https module.

```
var https = require('https');
var options = {
    host:'www.example.com',
    post: 80,
    path:'/post',
    method:'POST'
};
var req = https.request(options,(res) => {
  console.log(`STATUS: ${res.statusCode}`);
  console.log(`HEADERS: ${JSON.stringify(res.headers)}`);
  res.setEncoding('utf8');
  res.on('data', (chunk) => {
    console.log(`BODY: ${chunk}`);
  });
  res.on('end', () => {
    console.log('No more data in response.');
  });
});
req.write('{"name":"biblo","occupation":"Burglar"}');
req.end();
```

There are still a lot of similar modules. [axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios) is a famous for its promise responses.